# Prove $\cot\frac{\theta}{2} - 2\cot\theta = \tan\frac{\theta}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry

This is a math exercise I am doing for my year 10 math class. Basically I would like to show how I would prove that $\cot\frac{\theta}{2} - 2\cot\theta = \tan\frac{\theta}{2}$

I was able to expand the LHS and was able to use fractions to get that $$\cot\frac{\theta}{2} - 2\cot\theta = \tan\frac{\theta}{2} = \frac{\cos\frac{\theta}{2} - 2\cos\theta}{\sin\theta}$$

I do not know what I would do from here.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

suppose $\quad x=\frac \theta 2\quad$so that $\quad \theta=2x$:
$$\cot x-2\cot 2x=\frac {\cos x}{\sin x}-2\frac{\cos 2x}{\sin 2x}=\frac {2\cos^2x-2(\cos^2x-\sin^2x)}{\sin 2x}=\cdots $$

Comment: I forgot you could do that! Thank you very much.

Comment: @verygood101 encourage yourself to take any and all alternative pathways you can envision with algebra.  It's liberating

Answer (score 2):

$\cot \theta=\frac {\cos \theta} {\sin \theta}=\frac {\cos^{2}\frac {\theta} 2 -\sin^{2}\frac {\theta} 2} {2\sin (\frac {\theta} 2) \cos (\frac {\theta} 2)}$. Split this into two terms.

Answer (score 1):

An easier method...

Use the identities $\displaystyle \cot \frac {\theta}{2} = \csc {\theta} + \cot \theta$ and $\displaystyle \tan \frac {\theta}{2} = \csc {\theta} - \cot \theta$  and replace as needed.

The answer follows very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{align}\frac{1}{2}(\cot\frac{\theta}{2} - \tan\frac{\theta}{2})&=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1-\tan^2\frac{\theta}{2}}{\tan\frac{\theta}{2}}\\&  =\frac{1}{\frac{2\tan\frac{\theta}{2}}{1-\tan^2\frac{\theta}{2}}}\\&=\frac{1}{\tan\theta} \\&=\cot\theta\end{align}$